# Creating instance of the COM component with CLSID {..} from the IClassFactory failed due to the following error 800a0005 CTL_E_ILLEGALFUNCTIONCALL

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, iis

My **web API** (c# .net 4.7..), hosted on IIS (Windows 10), in order to run properly, requires a piece of software installed on the PC where the IIS is. This piece of software is written in VB and it **needs to be running** in order for the web-API to start up properly.
The web API is referencing some VB functionality via interop and COM registered dlls.

In Task-manager, i observe that IIS\worker process instead of referencing my running VB6 process, starts a new instance of the VB software (but not properly - and some variables are not loaded in this second instance - i assume this) hence i get the following error:

Creating an instance of the COM component with CLSID {...} from the IClassFactory failed due to the following error: 800a0005 Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A0005 (CTL_E_ILLEGALFUNCTIONCALL).

I have configured IIS and the app pool identity and authentication so that IIS/worker process is starting as the same user as the VB software is run as (both elevated).

I am not sure on how to force the w3w worker process to see the already running VB exe and prevent it from running a new instance of it.

When I am developing in visual studio 2019, and the web API is run via IIS express, everything works fine.

Thank you

Comment: maybe the problem is that iis worker is 64bit and vb code 32bit

Comment: in application pool, advanced settings i have Eanble 32-bit Applcation set to true.

Comment: does vb exe has any visible window? maybe you should also check interact with desktop in iis service (just blind guessing) ... and back to 32/64 problem check - if VB object is registered in WOW6432Node ... `visual studio 2019` is 32bit app so maybe its running IIS express in some 32 mode - so it's working when you debugging

Comment: @Selvin i couldnt edit the first comment so here a more complete answer: 
in application pool, advanced settings i have Enable 32-bit Application set to true.
It runs the vb6 code to some line so it is compatible. It crashes the vb6 part because a function is missing something. This missing something is loaded in the first instance of vb6 fully but not in the second instance.

Comment: @Selvin Yes, the vb app has a UI aswell, also running as part of the first instance. I beleivi this is the right direction in which i have to go in order to solve this.

Comment: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/ask-the-performance-team/application-compatibility-session-0-isolation/ba-p/372361 It's not likely to be an easy case as Windows isolates IIS web apps in session 0, while your own desktop and the VB 6 app in another. If you cannot modify the VB 6 app to be compatible with session isolation, you have to interop with it in the same session, not from session 0.

Comment: @LexLi what about spawing vb process from iis itself (I mean Process.Start) of course if this is the only requirements of OP(I mean if the only requirement to get valid COM object is COM server running in another process and you don't need to setup it from UI)

Comment: The VB application is a full desktop application which for itself requires a user to log in. This application has to be running so the belonging exe are there and so on. Only then the other c# apps manage to use the vb functionality.
I am thinking on how to bring both, the web APi and the VB application in the same session. Can a VB desktop app be run in Session 0? (I am in the process of investigating this). Or bring both webAPI and VB app into user Session or "Session 1" or whatever it would be, like it is working with IIS Express through visual studio. IIS Express on production PC?

Comment: And use Jexus manager ? : )

Comment: @Selvin No, I don't expect that to work. Most applications with GUI are never intended to work under session 0, https://blog.lextudio.com/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3

Comment: @Sed IIS Express is not for production, so you'd better avoid that. What kind of data do you need from that VB6 app? You can build a proxy app to run in the same session of that VB6 app, and then use a common inter-process communication mechanism (such as gRPC) to bridge your web app on IIS and that proxy app.

Comment: @LexLi The VB app, once run, loads a bunch of data and prepares stuff. Its like a black box.
I use this data and some other data that i prepare on my side, to send it back to VB. VB then performs again some somewhat complex algorithms in order to save this into an MS SQL database, again like a black box.

Comment: What @LexLi has said is all true.  In your situation I would be really questioning the current architecture of your applications.  The web app will need to be able to spawn it's own process independently of what ever else the system is running.  Your choices are really to either build more of the "Black Box" into ether the Web app, or the COM interface to allow it to run in the web service processes